# How can I view the request logs being sent to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API from Google Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-cloud-speech, unimrcp

Situation: We are using the UniMRCP Google Dialogflow plugin to proxy a request from a Cisco telephony stack to Google Dialogflow. In the request sent to UniMRCP, we are sending both audio and phrase hints, however we are unsure of whether the phrase hints are actually being passed along to Google Dialogflow/Google STT.

How can I view the logs of the request being sent to Google Cloud STT, so that I can confirm the presence or absence of the phrase hints?

I have already tried enabling Dialogflow logs by going to 'Settings' -> 'General' -> and enabling 'Log interactions to Google Cloud'.  However, these logs only log the request to Dialogflow after the speech to text transcription, and give me no indication of what was originally sent to Dialogflow, and what was originally sent to Cloud STT.

I have also been told I could "enable cloud speech logging" by following the procedure outlined in this link:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enable-data-logging.  However, I think this is more for allowing Google to make use of your data, and I can not find any additional logging.

Comment: Perhaps setup a dummy endpoint and get a packet trace?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe there is much ability to edit the configurations of the UniMRCP GDF plugin in that regards

Comment: Hi Ryan, could you solve this problem? I'm in the same situation, need to see the Google Cloud STT request , and can't find anything. Ty

Comment: sorry no, we dropped that project